# Is there a complete list of Abrahamic texts?

Tags: abrahamic-religions

I am trying to develop a comprehensive understanding of the mythology built around the Abrahamic religions. To that end I was trying to find every historical religious text about the Abrahamic religions, whether that be the Tanakh, the New Testament, the Quran, the Book of Mormon, the Apocrypha, the Gnostic Gospels, the Divine Comedy, Paradise Lost, the Temptation of St. Anthony, etc.

That is to say, I was primarily interested in the various paranormal elements like angels, demons, genies, aeons, archons, nephilim, Heaven, Hell, Purgatory, Qlippoth, Sheol, Lilith, Lucifer, Iblis, Yahweh, Yaldabaoth, Samael, etc.

Comment: My understanding is that most of this material comes from commentaries or apocrypha.  (You may want to ask over on [SE:MiYodeyah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/).  Despite common mythology surrounding Hell in the Old Testament, there are only a few, indirect references to sheol, etc., and the expansion of these concepts to the Greek Hades does not derive from the Old Testament proper.

Comment: Have you visited sacred-texts.com ? They have a vast collection that is searchable from the main page, as well as by categories.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Louis Ginzberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Ginzberg)'s *[Legends of the Jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legends_of_the_Jews)*. It is a pretty comprehensive collection of such texts. The first four volumes are available online [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/loj/index.htm).